# Generar método en java que retorne la película de menor duración del pasajero

Tags: java

Debo de generar un método en java que retorne la película de menor duración del pasajero. En caso que no tenga películas, retorna null, tengo el siguiente código y cuando lo ejecuto me manda el siguiente error: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
public Pelicula darPeliculaMasCorta() {
    Pelicula menor=null;
    
    if(peliculas.size()>0){
        for (int i=0;i < peliculas.size();i++ ){
            for(int j=i+1; j<peliculas.size(); j++){
                if(peliculas.get(i).darDuracion() == peliculas.get(j).darDuracion()){
                    return menor=peliculas.get(i);
                }else{
                    if(peliculas.get(i).darDuracion() > peliculas.get(j).darDuracion()){
                    return menor=peliculas.get(i);
                }
                }
            }
        }   
        
    }
    return menor;
}
```

Comment: Con respecto al error [NullPointerException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados) . En cuanto al método, el tipo de la 'duración' es un int u otro tipo.

Comment: inicializas menor en null, ahora las null pointer exception se dan por no inicilizar un valor, prueba mejor con `Pelicula menor = new Pelicula();`

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Pero si le pongo new Pelicula me sale el siguiente error: error: constructor Pelicula in class Pelicula cannot be applied to given types;
Pelicula menor= new Pelicula();